# Software to wake up iMac when an AFP request is made from another computer?

Tags: osx, sharing

Is there some software I can use to wake my iMac (10.9.5) up from sleep when I make an AFP request from another computer?

The Wake on Network access functionality doesn't work for AFP file sharing access, for some reason.

Comment: Wake for Network Access is known to be very flaky. I would suggest taking a look at the following Apple article to see if there is anything in it that you are not already doing. [About Wake on Demand and Bonjour Sleep Proxy](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201960)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not adverse to adding an extra step, you may consider using a **wake-on-lan** program. I'm assuming you are accessing from a Mac, as you are using AFP, so the following recommendations will be for OS X.

If you're comfortable with the terminal, I've had a good experience with [wolcmd](http://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/wake-on-lan-for-apple-mac.aspx).

A **GUI** option that works as well (and has the added benefit of discovering the appropriate information) that I have used is [wakeonlan](http://www.readpixel.com/wakeonlan/), by ReadPixel - it says it runs on 10.3-10.5, but I can confirm it is still working on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.

Ensure that "Wake for Network Access" is enabled in the preferences for the target Mac.

Comment: Thanks, but it's a work computer that I need to be able to wake up from home. In other words, from outside the LAN. And yes, from a Mac.

Comment: Oh, I see that with wakeonlan you can add an external host. I was hoping there would be something that's easier to setup. Many unskilled client-users need access to the file sharing on this machine.

Comment: Is the work computer behind NAT or does it have a public IP of its own?

Comment: It has a public IP.

Comment: You could consider using an executable shell script that uses wakeonlan, then put that on your users' desktops such that they could simply double-click it and it would run.